# Spring JPA - @Autowired Repository fails to load using @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project where I use @Autowire to load multiple repositories into a service class. The service class is in project C, while the repositories I need to use are located in two other projects, project A and project B. The error I initially got was:

```
Field userRepo in com.example.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.users.persistence.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
```

UserRepository is located in project A.
The solution to this error was to add @ComponentScan("com.example") to the controller class. After some other error fixes, I got the same error with another repository.

```
Field tenantRepo in com.example.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.commons.persistence.repository.TenantRepository' that could not be found.
```

TenantRepository is located in project B.
The thing is that both projects A and B are located under the package "com.example", where A is under "com.example.users", B is under "com.example.commons".

In this case, the @ComponentScan("com.example") annotation should have fixed both errors, but for some reason the repositories in project B are not loaded. 
This happens with all repositories in project B, if I add (required=false) to @Autowired TenantRepository [which I don't want to do as it is needed], I get the same error with the next repository from B. Project C that contains the service class is located under "com.example.users".

I have tried different variations of @ComponentScan, multiple package declaration, using basePackageClasses; but I still get the same error. What could be the problem in this case? Is there a solution using annotations (as the whole project is based on them and I don't really want to use xml if possible)?

Comment: during runtime , are you sure that the classpath is properly exported ? Can you check inside your war/jar ,  if it has both the project A and B ? Also what do you mean by *@ComponentScan("com.example") to the controller class* , you meant in a Configuration class right ?

Comment: which, of course, is Spring Data JPA API, which is != JPA API. Tags fixed

Comment: I agree with @AntJavaDev this sounds like a classpath issue. I'd recommend actually  printing the classpath at runtime, to see if it contains the paths where the classes are contained.

Comment: I was able to make the application run by moving the ComponentScan to the application class, thus I have ComponentScan SpringBootApplication. I am still quite new to this so I will check the other answers (as it is running, but not working correctly), but for now I guess this part is solved. Thanks.